# How to target content with no class inside a table in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which is generated by WooCommerce and a couple other plugins. I would like to get rid of that non-breaking-space and semicolon `&nbsp;:`. I know the proper way to do this will be to remove it from the PHP code itself, but I’ve spent hours looking for it without any luck, so I thought I would just hide it with JS, however I’m finding no way to target that `&nbsp;:` without affecting the other two `span` inside the `td`.

```
<tr class="shipping">
    <th>Shipping</th>
    <td data-title="Shipping">
        &nbsp;: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>350.00
        </span> 
        <input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" value="per_product" class="shipping_method" />     
    </td>
</tr>
```

So far I have this

```
$('.shipping').('td').css("display", "none");
```

Which hides the `&nbsp;:` plus the 2 `spans`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps

```js
$('.shipping td').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace('&nbsp;:', '');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="shipping">
    <th>Shipping</th>
    <td data-title="Shipping">
      &nbsp;: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>350.00
      </span>
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" value="per_product" class="shipping_method" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Keep in mind that if there are bound event handlers on the elements in the `td` they will be lost with this code.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you! :) Marking this answer as correct.